# R write_delim acts strange with quoted strings

Tags: r

```
regel <- 'string with "double" quotes in it'
uit <- data.frame(regel)

write_delim(uit,"test.file",col_names=FALSE,
            quote = "none")
```

result in a file containing:
string with ""double"" quotes in it

So, the quotes appears twice. How can I avoid this?

Thanks for your help.
Ton

Comment: The `escape` argument controls how quotes within the data are escaped.  The default behavior is for quotes to be doubled.  For no escaping of quotes use the argument `escape = "none"`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was most helpfull.